# Xamarin Studio: Can't display axml content mode

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I'm new to Mono for Android. I've developed android apps using eclipse and i often use drag-and-drop feature on editing UI. Recently, I followed Hello Android tutorial on http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello%2C_world and I didn't have any problem running the app on emulator. I easily modify layouts on source mode but xamarin studio seems to have problem rendering the UI on content mode:

```
mono.android.DesignerException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x1110009.
at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:129)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:462)
at mono.android.ListenerThread.processMessages(HostProcessConnection.java:182)
at mono.android.ListenerThread.run(HostProcessConnection.java:156)
```

Anyone experienced this problem?

This is the source of axml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/showSecond"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btntext" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What I have found is that things that work in eclipse don't always work in the Xamarin Studio editor. For better or worse it is more sensitive.

Comment: It can't even display the contents of the default layout - Main.axml.

Comment: I would imagine there is an error in your xml that Eclipse is ignoring but Xamarin crashing on. If you post your xml we can probably help you.

Comment: @snowCrabs, the source is now included on the post.

Comment: I am sorry I really assumed it was a more complicated XML than that. I just ran your source in my Xamarin studio Designer and it worked fine. I would report this on xamarin bugzilla. Check for updates and if that doesn't work I would uninstall/reinstall

Comment: I see... :( Ok, I'll try to update or reinstall the studio. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It just found a bug similar to this : [Bug 29068](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29068).

I removed and re-added all codes, It fixes my exception.

I think it will work for you too.

Similar post in Xamarin.Forms too : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/38961/cant-work-in-xamarin-studio-designer-xamarin-designer-designerexception-was-trown